# слайдер с фиксированным текстом слева

Tags: слайдер

Всем привет!) Прошу пожалуйста помочь новичку..
Нужно сделать следующее:
[image: слайдер с фиксированным текстом слева]

То есть, что бы текст изменялся внутри своего блока при прокрутке картинок с годами

Пытался сделать с owl и slick, не получилось..

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть..
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.slider-for').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: false,
fade: true,
asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 1,
asNavFor: '.slider-for',
dots: true,
focusOnSelect: true
});
});

Всем спасибо))